# Can $A$ and $B$ be independent of each other?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

> If event $A$ is dependent on event $R$ and so is even $B$, but there is no direct relation between $A$ and $B$. Can $A$ and $B$ be independent of each other?

To give an example, suppose there is a $\dfrac23$ chance that it rains today, and that the credibility of person $A$ is $\dfrac45$ and the credibility of person $B$ is $\dfrac13$. This implies that the response of person $A$ is dependent on whether it rains and so is the response of person $B$, but can I consider that the response of person $A$ is not at all dependent on the response of person $B$?

Comment: How do you define “credibility”? Does the same number describe the conditional probability of a truthful answer when it is raining and the conditional probability of a truthful answer when it is not raining? If so, the example is not a general example of the thing described in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the general question, of course, is yes.

Regarding the specific example, let $R$ be the event that it is raining,
let $T_A$ (respectively $T_B$) be the event that $A$ (resp. $B$) tells the truth,
and let $R_A$ (respectively $R_B$) be the event that $A$ (resp. $B$) says that it is raining.

Note that $R_A = (R \cap T_A) \cup (R^\complement \cap T_A^\complement).$

We are given that $P(R) = \frac23,$ $P(T_A) = \frac45,$ and $P(T_B) = \frac13.$

Where we go from here depends on other assumptions.

### Interpretation I

Let's suppose that $T_A,$ $T_B,$ and $R$ are all pairwise independent.
That is, $A$ is equally likely to lie regardless of the weather,
the same can be said for $B,$
and $A$ is equally likely to lie regardless of whether $B$ lies.
We can then calculate that 
$P(R_A) = \frac45\cdot\frac23 + \frac15\cdot\frac13 = \frac35,$
$P(R_B) = \frac13\cdot\frac23 + \frac23\cdot\frac13 = \frac49,$
and
$$P(R_A, R_B) = \frac45\cdot\frac13\cdot\frac23 + \frac15\cdot\frac23\cdot\frac13
 = \frac29 \neq P(R_A)P(R_B).$$
That is, for the particular events defined with these particularly stringent definitions, the responses of $A$ and $B$ are not independent.

### Interpretation II

Suppose we assume that $T_A$ and $T_B$ are independent of each other but we do not assume either is independent of $R.$
Then one possible way to model the problem is that $B$ always says it is not raining. Then $P(T_B) = \frac13,$ as required, but $R_B$ is independent of any other event,
including $R_A.$

Under this interpretation, the following statement is **false:**

> This implies that the response of person $A$ is dependent on whether it rains and so is the response of person $B.$

### Interpretation III

Suppose we assume that $T_A$ and $T_B$ are independent of each other, we do not assume either is independent of $R,$ but we forbid any of the events individually named above from having probability $0$ or $1.$
One possible model then assumes $T_A$ is independent of $R$ and
sets 
$$P(R, R_A, R_B) = P(R, R_A^\complement, R_B) = \frac1{60}$$
and
$$P(R^\complement, R_A, R_B) = P(R^\complement, R_A^\complement, R_B) = \frac1{30}.$$
The probabilities of other events are then determined,
it is still true that $P(T_B) = \frac13,$
and $R_B$ is independent of $R_A.$

This is easiest to model if $B$ waits to hear $A$'s response and then randomly chooses a response with a probability depending on whether it is raining and whether $A$ said it is raining.
Both the responses of $A$ and $B$ depend on whether it is raining, and whether each tells the *truth* is dependent in probability on whether the other does,
but the things $A$ and $B$ actually *say* ("raining" or "not raining") are independent of each other.

### Conclusion

The answer to this question,

> If event $A$ is dependent on event $R$ and so is even $B$, but there is no direct relation between $A$ and $B$. Can $A$ and $B$ be independent of each other?

is **yes** in general. 
It can be **yes** for the example given in the question.
But we can make some plausible additional assumptions in that example
that cause the answer to be **no** under those additional constraints.

Answer (score 4):

Throw two fair coins.

Let $A$ be the event that coin1 gives heads.

Let $B$ be the event that coin2 gives heads.

Let $R$ be the event that both coins give heads.

Then $A$ and $B$ are independent, and are both depending on $R$.

---

Answer (score 0):

Example: Let $R$ take values from $00$ to $99$ with uniform probability. Let $A$ be the first decimal digit of $R$, and $B$ the last digit.